# Store smarty variable in PHP variable

Tags: php, html, mysql, smarty

Please tell me how to store smarty variable in PHP variable

`Smarty variable = {$v.user_id}`

I want

```
<?php
      $var = {$v.user_id}
?>
```

Please tell me possible option

Comment: this is not a way to store smarty variable. exactly what you want to do? because php assign the variable to smarty and you are doing exactly opposite!!

Comment: Isn't the smarty notation simply applying `$v.user_id` at some location in a view template?  You shouldn't have any reason to "store a smarty variable in a PHP variable."  The template gets all of its data from objects that are already in the PHP code.  Wherever you're passing data to the template engine, that's where you have your PHP variable.

Comment: You meen there is no way..........
Actually script classes is encoded by ioncube..that's reason

Just tell me plz how i can run mysql query in template.....

$sql = ("select * from class_users where id={$v.user_id}");<---Not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where exactly do you want it to work? in php

```
$var = $this->_tpl_vars['v']['user_id'];
```

or in smarty

```
{assign var="var" value=$v.user_id}
```

Comment: LOL sorry to hear that :P judging by that comment You want answer on golden plate and that's why I think You will wait much longer...

Answer (score 2):

in smarty template file, use this to assign a value to variables.

```
{assign var=var value=$v.user_id}
```

ex:-

In PHP file you want to assign values to variable use this:

```
$smarty->assign('Name','Ajithkumar');
```

Smarty template file:

```
{$Name}
```

now you can get a name Ajithkumar.